# cakephp ignores numeric validation - saves everything

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

my problem is that the numeric validation in cakephp doesn't work for one model. I can't find the reason. Other validations in this model work fine, like email...

my rules:

```
...
'fone' => array(
    'Not empty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter your fonenumber.'
    ),
    'Numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter your fonenumber.'
    )
),
...
```

The db-field is varchar, and if I try something like 123abc it is saved. No error-message!

I tried:

```
public function beforeValidate($options) {
    debug($this->data);
    exit;
}
```

to see if the fields are transmitted - they are, else the values wouldn't be saved.

$this->Address->save($this->request->data) returns always true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dont need both rules. numeric already includes not empty (except for the 0 maybe). Also try to avoid spaces in your keys.

Comment: okay, I changed the keys (no spaces) but no change. I also tried small letters but same problem, I also read in your blog about fieldlists but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

try changing to this

```
'fone' => array(
    'Numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter your fonenumber.'
    ),
    'Not empty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter your fonenumber.'
    ),
),
```

Hoping it helps.

Comment: Thanks but returns true too, I also tried only numeric but no change. by the way notEmpty-Rule works fine... If I try a custom rule, It is ignored too - even when I type $this->Address->save($this->request->data, true); which should force the validation

Comment: which version of cakephp are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

it was my fault... I had an uninvalidate Function in the Model, which was called in the controller. I found it by checking other forms which access this model

- Sorry!!!